# How to clean up, shrink, or move Reaper undo files?

Tags: software, daw

I've been using Reaper (v5.15, recently upgrade from v4.75) for a while and up  to now have found it amazing - but now I'm not so sure.

I've accumulated 12 Gigs of background files for tracks I have made using Reaper. After completing each version of a project I have saved it twice - on the desktop and on the remote hard drive. The latest version of my latest project has a RPP UNDO file of 320MB, which perhaps explains why it takes ages to load, longer to save, and I think it is slowing up responses to mods/editing(?)

I've tried backing up the undo files etc. for a project then deleted the originals to test but when open the project it says some files are missing and when I browse in the backup folder no files are shown. I've read the user guide until I'm blue in the face and am at my wit's end.

Just for information I run Windows 7 Home Premium 32 bit.

Comment: These days,  12GB  is nothing to bother with.  If you get up to 150G, then maybe it's time for housecleaning.

Comment: Hi Carl - yes I guess it's all relative but the reason it bothers me is that saving further mods to such a project takes about 20  minutes which is a big waste of what little creative time I can spend at present - maybe I should get a more powerful computer? (I'm running an HP Mini netbook at present - any thoughts?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening is that Reaper is keeping the entire undo history of your project(s) and when you close the project, it saves the undo history to a file. When you open the project again, it loads the entire undo history of the project into memory. When the undo history becomes large enough, it takes up so much memory that your performance suffers.

Of course, you might want a deep undo history. So the question is, how far back do you want to be able to undo and how much performance are you willing to sacrifice? Or vice-versa, how much performance do you need and how much of your undo history are you willing to sacrifice?

Go into Reaper Preferences and look at the General tab/section/page:

[image: Reaper General Preferences]

There are many options that affect undo. Here are some ways to reduce your undo history size and increase your performance:

- Lower the maximum undo memory use size or disable undo (disabling is probably not a good idea)
- Uncheck "Allow load of undo history" (you won't be able to undo to back before your current session)
- Uncheck "Store Multiple Redo Paths"
- Uncheck "Create undo points for item/track selection" and/or "for loop selection"

See here for more details on the undo settings: http://wiki.cockos.com/wiki/index.php/Preferences_General

Comment: Hi Todd -thought I'd already posted this but it disappeared!just accessed your reply - I'm using Reaper v5.15 now- I updated it from v4.75 a few days back - I'll check out your link later tonight – David P 3 mins ago    edit   - sent 18.15 030316